# Models referring to each other - how can I most efficiently fix this issue?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django application that contains two models - `Company` and `User`. These are each in separate files. Each `User` has a `Company` by a `model.ForeignKey` field:

company.py:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

user.py:

```
# Ignore the clumsy in this import for a moment
from package.models.company import Company

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

Now, one thing I want to do is to add a method `list_admins` to `Company` (*not* `User`), whereby it would give me a list of all users who happen to have `is_admin` set to `True`:

```
    def list_admins(self):
        return User.object.filter(is_admin=True);
```

But of course that would require me to import `User` in Company, which I can't, as I can't import `User` in `Company` and `Company` in `User` at the same time owing to its circularity.

So how does one resolve this in a Pythonic/Djangoic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the reverse `ForeignKey` relation on each `Company` to access their respective `Users`:

```
def list_admins(self):
    return self.user_set.filter(is_admin=True)
```

---

Doc. reference: [Following relationships “backward”](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Answer (score -1):

```
def list_admins(self):
    return User.object.filter(company__is_admin=True);
```

Comment: That... does not solve much of the problem, I'm afraid. It will still require me to import User to the file declaring Company, which I can't, as I already have imported Company into the file declaring User.

Comment: if you want to return User objects you have to put this function in the User model. Otherwise... no sense

Comment: Nope, see above - you can return user models from a model invoked by the user model.